# HQL query: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Tags: hibernate, hql, alias

I got following 2 objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "A.searchById", query = "SELECT myCollection FROM A WHERE id = :id"),
... })
public class B{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "B_ID")
    int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery({several named queries...})
public class A{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "MAPPING_B_A", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID") },    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID") })
    List<B> myCollection;
}
```

I issue the following query:

```
SELECT myCollection FROM A WHERE id = :id
```

Hibernate returns: **Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'**

I alter my query into

```
SELECT myCollection FROM A as a WHERE a.id = :id
```

and everything works. But what was the problem with the first query? OK there is an id column in both classes but there is only one class in the FROM clause! I also experimented with changing the name of the id field in one of the classes, that did not help.

Comment: Your queries are just fine so it must be configuration. Since I don't see annotations I assume you are using XML config. Can you post the relevant part?

Comment: Actually, I use annotations. I did not posted them, sorry. I updated my question now.

Comment: So I assume that in your DAO you call the named query. Can you try executing the HQL directly instead (so not call the named query).

Comment: @StijnGeukens Exactly, that's the way I do it in my DAO. Now, as you suggested, I tried to supply the query string directly:  `Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT myCollection FROM A WHERE id = " + id);`    That did not help, I get the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-where) it should work without an alias

```
from Cat where name='Fritz'
```

The only other thing that comes to my mind is that `id` is reserved word, and that causes the problem. You can try with a different filed, to check if that is the case.

Comment: I also thought about that possibility and tried with another field -"name". I got an error again but with a different error message. It was about column "name" being ambiguous.

Comment: `id` is a 'reserved' word in HQL in the sense that it is an alias for the @Id field. So even if your field would be called `myAId`you can still refer to it with `id` in your HQL.

Comment: @StijnGeukens Nice, didn't know that detail

Comment: @EwgenijSokolovski "name" being ambiguous shouldn't happen in this simple case, are you sure you didn't forget to post some important detail (I assume this is just simplified code in the example)? Do you have some inheritance between your entities?

Comment: @PredragMaric Hmm, I omitted my annotations in the post. Maybe they could be the reason? I added them now.

Comment: And no, I do not have any inheritance between my items. Both of them implement the java.io.Serializable interface, however.

Comment: Everything looks ok to me, the only thing is that you declare your fields with default access modifier. Can you try to make them private, and add getters and setters? Maybe Hibernate can't access them in certain cases.